# Keras: trainable placeholders or layer weights per sample

Tags: keras

I'm using Keras. My goal is to build an autoencoder that learns an additional per-sample latent code. Here is some math to explain my problem: let `zᵢ = e(xᵢ;a)` be the encoder and `yᵢ = d(zᵢ;b)` be the decoder, where `xᵢ` are the inputs, `yᵢ` are the outputs, `zᵢ` are the latent codes, and `a`, `b` are the parameters of the encoder and decoder, respectively. A normal autoencoder training task is to minimize the loss `L(.,.)` with respect to the weights `a` and `b`, i.e. `min_{a,b} L(xᵢ, d(e(xᵢ;a);b)) ∀i`.

I want to add an additional per-sample parameter `kᵢ` in the latent dimension which should be minimized as well, i.e. `min_{a,b,kᵢ} L(xᵢ, d(e(xᵢ;a)+kᵢ);b)`. However, `a` and `b` are normal model parameters that are shared across all samples of `xᵢ`, but `kᵢ` shall be a per sample parameter or weight.

I want to realize this model in keras. The easiest way would be to use the functional API and specify `kᵢ` as Input (placeholder). My main problem is that this input/placeholder would not be trainable.

Here is a minimal example program:

```
import numpy as np
import keras
import keras.layers as L
from keras.models import Model

x = L.Input([2])
enc = L.Dense(1, activation='tanh')
dec = L.Dense(2, activation='tanh')

k = L.Input([1])
z = enc(x)
y = dec(L.add([z,k]))
m = Model([x,k],y)

X = np.random.randn(10,2)  # my samples
K = np.random.randn(10,1)  # the latent code that should be learned

m.compile('sgd', 'mse')
m.fit([X,K],X)   # K won't update, obviously
```

As the comment says, K won't be trained. Is there a way to achieve what I want, i.e. make `K` trainable but keep the data outside the model? I know that this could be done using the low-level backend API. But this would require me to essentially re-implement all the high-level tools (optimizers, layers, etc.) which is the main reason why I want to use keras.

Comment: How do you identify a sample? You need to identify a sample to learn a per-sample params. Most obvious way is to use one-hot code, then the params k is the embedding. But how do you use the embedding in the model? Most obvious way is to use it as the first layer. Then the solution in keras is obvious. If you use it as additional input, you can refer to multiple inputs example for keras.

Comment: As @THN mentioned, if this parameter is not shared for all the input samples, then there must be a way to distinguish different inputs and use their corresponding parameter. Further, you cannot make the input data trainable since it is outside of the model and is only fed to the model.

Comment: See my example, keras will always pair all K and X together, that's how they are identified. What I need is make K trainable and let X non-trainable.